# Сортировка jQuery

Tags: jquery, сортировка

Скажите, как сделать сортировку дивов `<div data-time="..." data-rating="...></div>` с помощью jQuery?

Comment: как-то использовал плагин [jQuery.fn.sortElements](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)

Comment: Надеюсь [Здесь][1] Вы найдёте ответ на этот вопрос.


  [1]: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

С уважением.